# Exclude Current Post from Recent Posts Loop

Tags: get-posts, exclude

what would be the best way to exclude the current post I am viewing from this recent posts query. Thank You!

```
<?php
            global $post;
            if (in_category('top-lists')) {
                $myposts2 = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=0&category=7');
            }
            else if (in_category('playlists') || in_category('playlistall')) {
                $myposts2 = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=0&category=6,37');
            }
            else if (in_category('news') || in_category('news')) {
                    $myposts2 = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=0&category=95');
            }
            else {
                $myposts2 = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=0&category=-6,-7,-37,-95,-177');
            }

            foreach($myposts2 as $post) :
            ?>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This the `post__not_in` arg should work dandy for you:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 7,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
);
$myposts2 = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: @kaiser and Brian - Thanks for getting back to me, I put in the code but I am getting a map_array error ----

Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/sitemain/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 1709

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/sitemain/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 1709

Comment: Try the latest edit. Populate your arguments into an array.

Comment: Hm? Why me? @Brian Fegter answered. :)

Comment: ha :) I'm good. Always glad to help out.

Comment: Perfect, thanks everyone especially @BrianFegter !

Comment: I'm currently using this `<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>`. How do I implement yours into mine? Thanks!

Comment: @Jornes You can just use 'cat' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 5 in the example above.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your $args

```
'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() )
```

This way you won't have to deal with getting the current post ID and will potentially avoid errors with getting your ID. The get_the_ID() function just get the ID for you so you don't have to deal with or do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in active theme functions.php file

```
    function be_exclude_current_post( $args ) {
        if( is_singular() && !isset( $args['post__in'] ) )
            $args['post__not_in'] = array( get_the_ID() );
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'be_exclude_current_post' );
```